# Excel VBA - add date and time to a file name as FILENAME_MMDDYY_HHMMSS

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

A few weeks ago I posted about using VBA To prompt me to add a file name when saving an excel file using a macro. Thank you for all the help. I got it to work!!

Now I have another similar question.

How can I get the month, date, year --AND-- hour, minute,second in VBA then add it to the file name?
Why?
So when I click the macro to save it as an excel file and a PDF the FILENAME is "time stamped" and eliminates any issue of "OH NO! I overwrote the file with another one!!"

I tried a few things (again, not a VBA programmer by any means [ I work as a RN !!} ) but just cant get all the information.

Dim mydate as text
Mydate = date(now)
Dim month as text
mymonth = month(now)
..and similar for hour, minute, second, and year

Then concatenate all these together as a..... text ??.... string, then add it to the file name

In use thought process...

1. I'm making  changes to the file....change data, change a font.....
2. Date Time is: April 21, 2023 at 9:02;12 am
3. `<click the macro>` "the code" (LOL!!)
4. get the hour, minute, etc in `MMDDYY` (042123) and `HHMMSS` (090212) format
5. assign it to a variable.... call it FILESTAMP
6. at this point FILESTAMP is 042123_090212
7. concatenate it to the file name: FILENAME_042123_090212
8. File is saved as "FILENAME_041223_090212.xls"
9. work with the file some more...make changes....etc
10. five minutes pass....
11. click the macro to save etc.
12. save file is now named  FILENAME_042123_090712     <== "07" since 5 minutes have passed (2+5=7)

I use it for a financial worksheet and I think this is a good way to ensure saving the file

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? [`Now()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/now-function) may provide the string you are looking for

Comment: Sorry about that. Here's my attemmpt. I added the message box so it shows me the data its using.

Sub PW_033023_Rev_01()
'
' PW_033023_Rev_01 Macro

'============
Dim today
today = Now     ' make the 'now' as the changing variable for the file name
MsgBox ("Now is" & today)
'==========
'Dim time, hour
'time = hour
'MsgBox ("Hour is " & hour)
'===============
Dim myyear As Long
myyear = Year(Now)
MsgBox ("year is " & myyear)

Dim mymonth As Long
mymonth = Month(Now)

Dim mydate As Long
mydate = Day(Now)


'MsgBox ("Hour is " & hour)



End Sub

Comment: Could you add your code to the question - the edit button is just below the tags at the bottom of the question.  I tried adding it, but having trouble figuring out where one line ends and the next starts.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Sub MakeBackupFile()
Rem Save backup copy (if possible)
    Dim strPath
    Dim strFilename

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    strPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    If strPath Like "http*" Then Exit Sub   ' Saving copy is not working in SharePoint
    strPath = strPath & "\Backups\"
    If Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir strPath
    If Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then Exit Sub ' Cannot create subfolder Backups
    strFilename = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", "_" & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & "_" & Format(Time, "hhmmss") & ".")

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs strPath & strFilename
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
'    MsgBox "Make sure there is a subfolder named 'Backups' in the folder that holds this file."
End Sub
```

*Please note that the macro does not save the current file, but creates a copy of it with a timestamp in the Backup subdirectory. The timestamp is not what you asked for - the date is written in **year-month-day** order. This allows you to get the files in the right order simply by sorting them by name (in the case of **MMDDYY**, sorting by name would give the wrong sequence of files)*

Comment: That works!! THanks SOOOOO much!!!